# What are the uses for 'quick'?

Tags: meaning, idioms, vocabulary

Is the word quick ever used in reference to candles eg the quick of the candle? I know about the quick of the nail and obviously about the wick of a candle but I have a memory of the quick too being something to do with candles.

Comment: I don't think so. Either you, or someone you heard, has just mixed up *quick* and *wick*.

Comment: _Quick_ means 'living' (_the quick and the dead_), so the quick of a nail is the living part, where the nail is still growing. A candle, on the other hand, is not living, though its wick is sort of analogous, as the center. However, the wick is where the candle burns, and therefore diminishes, rather than growing. So, while the metaphor **Fire Is A Living Creature** is quite potent, one needs to avoid some incoherent features when using it.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting response. Wax can also seem living as it melts and forms life like organic shapes but agreed it is in a process of diminishing.

Comment: There is some obsure connection between candles/wicks and the word _quick_, though not really in English as such. In Old Norse (and still in Modern Icelandic), the verb meaning ‘light [a candle/fire]’ is _kveikja_, which is etymologically the same word, derived from the Proto-Germanic word for ‘live/alive/quick’—you literally ‘quicken’ the candle. The wick itself is _kveikr_ (Old Norse) or _kveikur_ (Modern Icelandic).

Comment: "**Burnt to the quick**" is applied to candles, but also to other things, such as matches, hands and strip clubs as well: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22burnt+to+the+quick%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#

Comment: I'll note that the soft inside of a horse's hoof is known as the "quick".

Answer (score 3):

Google finds only 9 instances of "quick of the candle", and one of those is this question!

*Quick* in these instances is clearly an [**eggcorn**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) for *wick*—

> In linguistics, an **eggcorn** is an idiosyncratic substitution of a word or phrase for a word or words that sound similar or identical in the speaker's dialect. The new phrase introduces a meaning that is different from the original, but plausible in the same context, such as "old-timers' disease" for "Alzheimer's disease". —*Wikipedia*

The original meaning of *quick* was “alive, living” which evolved quite naturally into “lively” and thus “fast”. The original meaning has almost disappeared, except in such fixed phrases as *cut me to the quick* (that is, to the ‘living’ part of my flesh) and *the quick and the dead*.

Answer (score 3):

Only metaphorically. Quick means either "with high speed" or "alive", the latter being a somewhat outdated usage. One could imagine some poetical description of a candle flame being alive.

```
The flame burned, consumed the wick,
As if the candle flame was quick.
```

(Ok I'm not a poet, just an example... :-)

More likely you heard "wick" rather than quick.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall hearing that phrase but it might be related to *quick* meaning [*alive*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33109/etymology-of-quick-of-a-fingernail-as-in-cut-to-the-quick) ie the candle is lit.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the phrase 'burn the (or a) candle to the quick', but that was long ago and I'm also searching for a reference to it.  It means to use something completely up, and I believe the 'quick' is the base part of the candle where the wick is either anchored or begins.